# Not Able to correctly align image with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this problem when trying to display images. I tried everything but I can't get it the propper way. 
Here's what it looks like.
 I'd like the second row of data to be right under the first one, and the image right next to it.
https://postimg.org/image/634nny3b9/

here's some of my code for that page

#### Datos personales

```
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <label for="ex1">Nombre</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" value="<?= $clientes->nombre ?>" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <label for="ex1">Apellido</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <label for="ex1">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="date" value="" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">

                 <img src="route/to/image" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <label for="ex1">Dirección</label>
                          <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>  
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <label for="ex2">DNI</label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="int" value="" disabled="disabled">
                    </div>                  

                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <label for="ex2">Telefono</label>
                          <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
```

```
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                              <label for="ex2">E-mail</label>
                              <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled">
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                  <label for="ex2">Sexo</label>
                                  <input class="form-control" id="ex2" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled">
                                </div>

         </fieldset>

<hr>
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that.

Comment: thanks, first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do basically is:

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-xs-9>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <!-- labels and inputs go here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <!-- labels and inputs go here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <!-- labels and inputs go here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3>
        <!-- image goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** And BTW, the question is totally unrelated to php. Consider removing the php tag.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked well for you.